# Allow MPMoviePlayerViewController to play in landscape while preserving presenting view controller's orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have a MPMoviePlayerViewController (a subclass rather, XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController) that I'm presenting with the following code

```
LPVideo *video = [_videos objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier: video.code];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

My issue is that while the entire app is locked in Portrait mode I still want the user to play videos in landscape, so I've put this in my AppDelegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
else
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
}
```

This works fine in allowing the user to watch the video in portrait orientation; however if the video player is dismissed in portrait mode the viewcontroller that presented has also switched to portrait, which is something I don't want happening.

I have tried all sorts of things, like implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` in my main UINavigationController, but it doesn't even prevent landscape orientation.

I know this is possible because I've seen apps doing this, but I can't figure out how. I've seen some solutions that involve listening to orientation changes and applying transformations to the player view but it seems needlessly complicated.

I also tried "forcing" rotation upon return via `viewWillAppear:animated` but while the code is called it doesn't help.

I've tried both this

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *view = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[view removeFromSuperview];
[window addSubview:view];
```

And this

`[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];`

Both achieve nothing.

Comment: Have you got an solution? I am facing the same issue.My app is in portrait mode, only MPMoviePlayerViewController should play video in landscape mode.Using supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow, I can play video in lanscape but after dismissing the playercontroller, app still remains in landscape mode which is not the orientation I support. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the answer below, it worked for me! (you have to implement my code in your AppDelegate but instead of self.window just use window)

Comment: Glad I could help, but I would've never go it if it wasn't for Shubham and their comment so they deserve all the credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is not that clear, if you wanna play video in all orientations then use "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll" instead of "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown".
If it doesn't work then check if any of the libraries you are using, changing the orientation.

Comment: Like I said after the first block of code the video player can rotate just fine; the problem is upon dismissing the player in landscape the ViewController that presented the movie player is in landscape as well, which is not an orientation I support — my question is how to prevent this behavior.

Comment: I faced same problem and it was because library i used[i.e. ViewDeck] was changing the orientation.So can you check for that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case; I just tried using the same code in a project that uses nothing but a UINavigationController and I'm getting the same result

Comment: replace "self.window" with "window" and it will work.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed the issue by checking  `isBeingDismissed`:

```
 - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
    {
        if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]] && ![[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
    }
```

but hey, I'm using Swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    //If the video is being presented, let the user change orientation, otherwise don't.
    if let presentedViewController = window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController? {
        if (presentedViewController.isKindOfClass(MPMoviePlayerViewController) && !presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed()) {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        }
    }
    return .Portrait
}
```

Comment: The above answer is good, but on dismiss it allows the screen to be in landscape. This forces everything back to portrait. Thanks.